# Alerting the user after a node js validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I alert the user after nodejs validation?

```
router.post('/clocking', async (req,res) => {
  const value = req.body.clock
  const id = req.body.empId
  try {
    if( value == 'in' ){
      const data = await Clocking.find({ employee: id }).populate('employee').lean()
      const i = data.length
      if(data[i-1].clockOut.getTime() == data[i-1].clockIn.getTime()) {
        // ....alert the user.....
      }else{
        await Clocking.create({ employee:id });
        res.redirect('/')
      }
    } 
  } catch (e) {}
})
```

How can I do such a thing in nodejs?

Comment: What do you mean when you say alert the user? You can send a response `res.send({message:'Alert'})` like this.

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala I want user to see the alert while he is in the same page where he submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Respond with something.

e.g.

```
res.render("error-page", { /* data about the error */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to notify the user? If your want to simple send a message, you can do it like that:

```js
router.post('/clocking', async (req, res) => {
  const value = req.body.clock
  const id = req.body.empId
  try {
    if (value === 'in') { // use `===`, not `==`
      const data = await Clocking.find({ employee: id }).populate('employee').lean()
      const i = data.length
      if (data[i - 1].clockOut.getTime() === data[i - 1].clockIn.getTime()) { // use `===`, not `==`
        res.send("The name is incorrect") // NEW
      } else {
        await Clocking.create({ employee: id });
        res.redirect('/')
      }

    }
  } catch (error) { // NEW
    res.send("There was an error", error) // NEW
  } // NEW
}
```

Comment: I want user to see the alert while he is in the same page where he submit the form

Comment: How is your app composed? Is it a Single Page Application (React, Vue, etc.) or do you use templates in Node applicaton?

Comment: I use templates(handlebars) no front-end libraries.

Comment: Then you need to create an error page that has a dynamic field `message`), and send something like `res.render("error-page", {message: "data in the wrong format"})` instead of `res.send` in my example

Comment: @iresh-madushanka, did you manage to solve this problem? :)

Comment: yeah i did render a error page but im finding a more convenient method like we see a error when we input wrong user name or password.